# Access the variable declared inside the private class in java

Tags: java, class, private, accessor

This is my code.

```
private void btnloginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String username = "";
    String sql = "select * from userinfo where uname=? and pword=?";
    try{
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, txt_username.getText());
        pst.setString(2, txt_password.getText());

        rs=pst.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next()){
            afterLogin pwcorrect = new afterLogin();
            pwcorrect.setVisible(true);
            this.setVisible(false);
            username = txt_username.getText();
        }
        else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username and Password are Incorrect.");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

I need to access the value of username from another class. Is there any way for this??? Please help me with code.

Comment: Define public accessors methods and use them.

Comment: i see **no** private class in your code, all i see is a private method with local variable username.

Comment: @PremGenError: I am sorry for that. Can you tell me how can i access this local variable username from other class or other method in same class? and can you please give code for that as well.

Comment: @user2068452 forget other class's, other methods in this very same class won't be able to access this local var username. local variables are only confined to the method they are declared in. the better option here would be to make it an private instance variable and have public setter and getter method throughwhich other class's can access username.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not just defined in the class, it's defined in a *method* in a class.

This isn't a "private" variable (or class), it's an *invisible* variable as far as other classes are concerned. Expose it with a public getter, or provide a mechanism the code can set it on something else.

Since this is an action handler you also need to make sure the variable will only be accessed after it's been set, or that however it's accessed can deal with it *not* having a value.

---

```java
public class WhateverClassThisIs {

    private String username;

    public String getUsername() { return username; }

    private void btnloginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        String sql = "select * from userinfo where uname=? and pword=?";
        try {
            // As before, but:
            if (rs.next()) {
                username = txt_username.getText();
            }
        }
    }
}

public class SomeOtherClass {

    private WhateverClassThisIs theOtherClass;

    public void setTheOtherClass(WhateverClassThisIs theOtherClass) {
        this.theOtherClass = theOtherClass;
    }

    public void whatever() {
        String username = theOtherClass.getUsername();
    }
}
```

The other mechanism would rely on passing something in to `WhateverClassThisIs` with a username setter, roughly:

```java
public class WhateverClassThisIs {

    private SomeOtherClass someOtherClass;

    public WhateverClassThisIs(SomeOtherClass someOtherClass) {
        this.someOtherClass = someOtherClass;
    }

    private void btnloginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        String sql = "select * from userinfo where uname=? and pword=?";
        try {
            // As before, but:
            if (rs.next()) {
                someOtherClass.setUsername(txt_username.getText());
            }
        }
    }
}

public class SomeOtherClass {

    private String username;

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public void whatever() {
        // Do something with username--but either try
        // after you know it's been set, or by being
        // able to handle it being null/empty/whatever
    }
}
```

In addition, you could use an `Observer`, any of several Swing-ish mechanisms, and so on.

Comment: "Expose it with a publicly getter, or provide a mechanism the code can set it on something else."
Can you explain this please with codes.

Comment: @user2068452 I suppose, although hopefully it was obvious in hindsight. There are several other ways to deal with this kind of situation, some Swing-specific, some not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are ways to do it using reflection ... if the variable is a field.

But the best solution is change the other class so that it has accessible getter and/or setter methods ... after you have thought through all of the implications.

Breaking a classes encapsulation to access private state is something you should only do as a last resort.

---

If the variable is a local variable, then there is NO way that some other class or method can update it.  And you can only access it from another class if that class is a locally declared anonymous inner class and the variable is declared as `final`.  That doesn't sound like what you are trying to do here ....

Comment: I am trying to get the username from text field if username and password is correct. So that i can use the username in other classes or methods.

Comment: So don't put it in a local variable!!!  Put it in a (private) field of the enclosing class and implement a getter method.  (If you ask the wrong question you won't get the right answer.  It pays to make the effort to express yourself *clearly* ...)